# calling Object.notify() before Object.wait()

Tags: java, concurrency, operating-system

If there is no thread which is waiting, using `Object.wait()` , any calls to `Object.notify()` or `Object.notifyAll()` have no effect. I have a scenario in which if I call `Object.notify()` when the wait set is empty, a subsequent call to `Object.wait()` should not put the thread to wait. How can this be accomplished? Semaphores may be one solution I can think of. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of scenario seems to be a perfect fit for a `Semaphore`. Call `Semaphore.release()` instead of `notify()` and `Semaphore.acquire()` instead of wait.

Answer (score 7):

Use a flag to indicating a notification.  Read the flag before entering wait and act accordingly.

```
boolean stopped = false;

public void run(){
   synchronized(object){
      while(!stopped)
        object.wait();
   }

}

public void stop(){
  synchronized(object){
    stopped=true;
    object.notify();
  }

}
```

Comment: +1: Any state change can record the fact that a notify() was called earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `Semaphore`, `CyclicBarrier` or possibly `CountDownLatch` - whichever is a better fit for your real scenario. I think it's a good idea to reuse existing abstractions rather than use the low-level mechanisms yourself, unless those mechanisms give you exactly the behaviour you want (which they don't in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I guess then Semaphore works the best for the scenario I have.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like this

Thread A:

```
 req.run();
synchronized (req) {
                    try {
                        req.wait(3000);
                        rawResponse = eq.ReturnXML;
                        logger.info("[" + refID + "] Response recieved: " + rawResponse);
                        responseRecieved = true;
                        req.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        logger.error("Error waiting on req", ex);
                    }
                }
```

Thread B:

```
synchronized (req) {
        while (!responseRecieved) {
            try {
                req.wait(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.error("Error waiting on req while trying to get state", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thread A makes the request and waits for a response, in the meanwhile Thread B is only waiting for the response. If a response has already arrived it does not wait.